# Xamarin.Android Continuous Integration and Testing with TFS 2013

Tags: xamarin.android, continuous-integration

For TFS 2013 (and the old XAML build configurations), how do you generate the APK file for an Android project? I keep building the project but I get this error in the log folder, even if I build the "Release" configuration

> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(618,5): warning : The OutputPath property is not set for project 'Project.Android.csproj'.  Please check to make sure that you have specified a valid combination of Configuration and Platform for this project.  Configuration='Release'  Platform='Mixed Platforms'.  You may be seeing this message because you are trying to build a project without a solution file, and have specified a non-default Configuration or Platform that doesn't exist for this project.

And nothing exists in the folder. I've followed the steps in the Xamarin Docs but it seems to not apply for TFS2013: 
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/ci/tfs_walkthrough/add-build-definition/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The UI for TFS2013 is quite similar when configuring the build definition. You have to supply some additional arguments to MSBuild under the "5. Advanced" sub-heading:

[image: MSBuild Arguments in Advanced Section]

You are getting the "OutputPath" error because you have not specified the output path for the build. Now for the APK, when building from command line  you have to provide an additional parameter: "/t:PackageForAndroid"

You have to put this in combined with the other MSBuild arguments for something like this:

```
/p:AndroidSdkDirectory=c:\android-sdk /p:Configuration=Release
/p:Platform="AnyCPU" /p:OutputPath="bin/Release" /t:PackageForAndroid
```

Your Build should then be successful, provided you don't have any other errors! Here's an example PowerShell script from our Xamarin Forums (around 2013) that includes signing and zip aligning as well:

```
# First clean the Release target.
msbuild.exe HelloWorld.csproj /p:Configuration=Release /t:Clean

# Now build the project, using the Release target.
msbuild.exe HelloWorld.csproj /p:Configuration=Release /t:PackageForAndroid /p:Platform="AnyCPU" /p:OutputPath="bin/Release"

# At this point there is only the unsigned APK - sign it.
# The script will pause here as jarsigner prompts for the password.
# It is possible to provide they keystore password for jarsigner.exe by adding an extra command line parameter -storepass, for example
#    -storepass <MY_SECRET_PASSWORD>
# If this script is to be checked in to source code control then it is not recommended to include the password as part of this script.

& 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.x.x\bin\jarsigner.exe' -verbose -sigalg MD5withRSA -digestalg SHA1  
-keystore ./xample.keystore -signedjar
./bin/Release/helloworld-signed.apk
./bin/Release/helloworld.apk publishingdoc

# Now zipalign it.  The -v parameter tells zipalign to verify the APK afterwards.

& 'C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\tools\zipalign.exe' -f -v 4
./bin/Release/helloworld.apk ./newAPK.apk
```

**For the signing and zip aligning,** you can refer to the [Xamarin.Android docs on this matter.](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/publishing_an_application/part_2_-_signing_the_android_application_package/manually-signing-the-apk/#Sign_the_APK)